# Parsing PDF to HTML using PDF2DOM returns null

Tags: java, html, pdf, dom

I am using [pdf2dom](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/pdf2dom/) and trying their basic documentation. Stated in their documentation - Pdf2Dom is based on the Apache PDFBox™ library.

```
File file = new File("file.pdf");
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(file);
PDFDomTree parser = new PDFDomTree();
Document dom = parser.createDOM(pdf);
System.out.println(dom);
```

What gets printed out - [#document: null]

Tried the same code with 3 different pdf's

When i strip the same PDF in text it returns the valid text. Thus the file is not null. Am i doing something wrong  or the library itself?

Stripper code if it helps.

```
PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(pFile);
PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String text = stripper.getText(pd);
System.out.println(text);
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your code. The `toString()` method of `Document` object returns that way.

[#document: null], consists of two parts. 
The first part is #document which is the node name. When you parse XML, you always receive a #document node as the top-level node. 
The second part is null, which is the value of the node. null is used to indicate that the node doesn't have a value.

If you print `dom.getDocumentElement().getTextContent()` then you should see some value.

Comment: Thanks , sorry for noob mistake